# How to select first and last TD in a row?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can you select the first and the last `TD` in a row?

```
tr > td[0],
tr > td[-1] {
/* styles */
}
```

Answer (score 414, accepted):

You could use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-selectors:

```
tr td:first-child,
tr td:last-child {
    /* styles */
}
```

This should work in all major browsers, but IE7 has some problems when elements are added dynamically (and it won't work in IE6).

Comment: and what if you want to select the second og third child?

Comment: and whats the difference between `tr > td` and `tr td`?

Comment: The following rule sets the style of all P elements that are children of BODY: body > P { line-height: 1.3 }  You can see at: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors (same page posted by James)

Comment: @clarkk - The `>` selects direct children only. Without it, all descendants (e.g. children of children) will be selected. To select the 2nd or 3rd child, look into the `nth-child` pseudo-selector.

Comment: @BoltClock I saw once your solution to this problem using `+` . something like  `tr td + td + .... +td`  but what if i dont know how many td's  i have ?

Comment: @Royi Namir: If you don't know how many you have, then you cannot select the last child using just CSS.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the following snippet:

```
  tr td:first-child {text-decoration: underline;}
  tr td:last-child {color: red;}
```

Using the following pseudo classes:

**:first-child**  means "select this element if it is the *first child* of its parent".

**:last-child** means "select this element if it is the *last child* of its parent".

Only element nodes (HTML tags) are affected, these pseudo-classes ignore text nodes.

Answer (score 19):

You could use the **:first-child** and **:last-child** `pseudo-selectors`:

```
tr td:first-child{
    color:red;
}
tr td:last-child {
    color:green
}
```

Or you can use other way like

```
// To first child 
tr td:nth-child(1){
    color:red;
}

// To last child 
tr td:nth-last-child(1){
    color:green;
}
```

Both way are perfectly working

Answer (score 5):

If you use sass(scss) you can use the following snippet:

```
tr > td{
   /* styles for all td*/
   &:first-child{
     /* styles for first */ 
   }
   &:last-child{
    /* styles for last*/
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If the row contains some leading (or trailing) `th` tags before the `td` you should use the `:first-of-type` and the `:last-of-type` selectors. Otherwise the first `td` won't be selected if it's not the first element of the row.

This gives:

```
td:first-of-type, td:last-of-type {
    /* styles */
}
```

Comment: you saved my time i was using last-child which was not working but your solution worked perfectly

Answer (score -1):

You can use

table tr td:first-child { css here
}
**for First Child and**

table tr td:last-child { css here
}
**for last Child**.