# How to style a field, which div id is unknown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to style a data filed in a table but its div id is unknown / unavailable, and cannot be written. here is the page source:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>        
        <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center;" name="">
            <div style="padding:0; margin:0;">Ford</div>
            <div style="display:none; padding:0; margin:0;"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center;" name="">
            <div style="padding:0; margin:0;">Crown Victoria</div>
            <div style="display:none; padding:0; margin:0;"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:center;" name="">
            <div style="padding:0; margin:0;">1234JESS123456789</div>
            <div style="display:none; padding:0; margin:0;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have to apply the following javascript on the last td.

```
<div id="output">ABC123DDD8877</div>

$('#output').html(($('#output').html()).replace(/[0-9]/gi, '<strong style="font-size:20pt">$&</strong>'))
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what style you want to apply and to which div

Comment: So the ID is unknown. Well, what ***is*** known?

Comment: Which `div` are you trying to style, the first one, the second one, or both?  What kinds of styles are you trying to apply?

Comment: Do you know the id of the table? Or the id of any elements containing the table?

Comment: Why are you doing HTML string manipulation? I'd really recommend going through some basic tutorials, and get an understanding of how the DOM works.

Comment: yes, the table id is known: please look into this http://jsfiddle.net/CWRLR/8/

Comment: <table id="multi-record-table"

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

If you want all divs to be styled then try this:

```
table td div{
    //Style here
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CWRLR/1/)

If you don't want to style all `divs` and only first div then try like this:

```
table td div:first-child{
   // your style
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CWRLR/2/)

Comment: All divs in the `td`s? I don't get that from the question.

Comment: Yes `divs` are his data-fields so it's all fields :)

Comment: *"I want to style a data filed..."* ;-)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Though, the request seems to be to somehow single one `<div>` out for these styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting it like this through CSS:

```
tbody tr td div {
    ...
}
```

Comment: dear all, thanks for you response. I am new so, couldn't reply promptly. here is my code and table: http://jsfiddle.net/CWRLR/8/

Answer (score 0):

If you know which div it is you could do something with first-child or last-child. here is a previous post about it. [How to select first and last TD in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228800/how-to-select-first-and-last-td-in-a-row)

Comment: this is 5th in 12 tds.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to accomplish this, but I'd recommend that you **not** do it. The responsible approach is to find a way to add a hook to a parent element - an ID or a class.

If you feel like you have no other way, then...you'd have to use the attribute selector:

```
td div[style]{
  color:blue;
  }
td div[style*="display"]{
  color:red;
  }
```

In example one, you target a div which contains a `style` attribute.

In example two, You're targeting an element by the presence of the `style` attribute, and querying to see if that `style` attribute would contain the value `display` - since, in your example, this is the only distinguishing difference between the two `style` attributes .

Essentially, you're styling an element by targeting its inline styles. This is how monsters are born, so please find another way.